# Typescript - Import Namespace Into Another Namespace

Tags: javascript, typescript, namespaces

I'm wondering if it's possible to export a namespace from one typescript .d.ts file and then import that namespace into another .d.ts file where it gets used inside of a namespace.

Example:

namespace_export.d.ts

```
export namespace Foo {
    interface foo {
        prop1: string;
    }
}
```

types.d.ts

```
import { Foo } from './namespace_export'

export namespace Types {
    Foo // <-- This doesn't work but is what I would like
    interface Bar {
        prop2: string
    }
}
```

testfile.ts

```
import { Types } from './types'

function testTypes(type: Types.Foo.foo) {
    console.log(type);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was wondering how to achieve this too. I found this solution:

```
import { Foo as fooAlias } from './namespace_export'
export namespace Types {
  export import Foo = fooAlias;
  interface Bar {
    prop2: string
  }
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: I dont' undestand how it works), can someone explain how interpreter understands 'export import'?